# callback function in socket as sk_data_ready()

Tags: c, linux, performance, networking, linux-kernel

I was trying to calculate the **CPU cycles consumed by various layers & functions defined in linux kernel for TCP/IP network stack for processing a packet**. so i used TSC for CPU consumtion by various functions. which shows that single call to  sk_data_ready() function takes a lot of CPU cycles.

So i follow the source code for TCP/IP stack in linux kernel for raw sockets & got the information as the packets are en-queued finally in the receiving circular linked list of the particular socket.

But after en-queuing the packet the **function defined in sock.c as sock_queue_rcv_skb() calls**

```
sk->sk_data_ready(sk, skb_len);
```

which is the callback function(i think). but i am not able to get any source code of this callback function.

can anyone help me to find the code & how it works?

does recvfrom() function is also related to the above defined callback function?

Comment: Have you tried grepping it? It shows a bunch of places where this callback is set or called, and those are more or less obvious.

Comment: Are you sure that sk_data_ready() actually takes a lot of cycles, or just takes a long time before it returns - in other words, it waits for data to become available, which means the processor goes and does other things? Otherwise http://lxr.linux.no is a good resource for figuring out where code goes... [As is "grep"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default ->sk_data_ready() callback is sock_def_readable():

```
static void sock_def_readable(struct sock *sk, int len)
{                       
        struct socket_wq *wq;

        rcu_read_lock();
        wq = rcu_dereference(sk->sk_wq);
        if (wq_has_sleeper(wq))
                wake_up_interruptible_sync_poll(&wq->wait, POLLIN | POLLPRI |
                                                POLLRDNORM | POLLRDBAND);
        sk_wake_async(sk, SOCK_WAKE_WAITD, POLL_IN);
        rcu_read_unlock();
}
```

which basically wakes up the process waiting for these data, for example, recv(), and let them process the data in ->sk_receive_queue.

Some protocol may override this, for example, netlink, see __netlink_kernel_create().

BTW, you can use `perf top` command to see which kernel function consumes most CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

```
void sock_init_data(struct socket *sock, struct sock *sk) 
{
    sk->sk_data_ready   =   sock_def_readable;
    sk->sk_write_space  =   sock_def_write_space;
    sk->sk_error_report =   sock_def_error_report;
}
```

Comment: Add some context to your code to help future readers better understand the purpose of your code.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.